# Is it possible for an iOS app to be killed by iOS before the 10 min limit

Tags: ios

So is this possible for an app that is running a background task ? Say for example that the iOS decides that there are memory constraints and wants to give more memory to an app in the foreground.

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely possible, and the behavior is well documented on the iOS developer site.

Comment: Well it says that it moves from suspended to terminated when there is memory pressure not from background. Can you provide a reference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From iOS documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

> *Every app should free up as much memory as is practical upon entering the background. The system tries to keep as many apps in memory at the same time as it can, but when memory runs low it terminates suspended apps to reclaim that memory. Apps that consume large amounts of memory while in the background are the first apps to be terminated.*

So, yes it is possible.